# MVC 4 Razor Html helper DispayFor not detecting string as boolean

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looping through rows and trying to make use of my DataTable Model.

```
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(d => d.Rows[i].ItemArray[j])</td>
```

Im passing in five values per Row, per ItemArray, the first two are strings, the other three are strings but are either "True" or "False". I thought DisplayFor would detect this and create a CheckBox for the boolean strings.

I get five strings. Do I need additional params?

Comment: No, you need to use the correct data types.

Comment: @podiluska - I tried casting it as bool but I get template errors, perhaps I need to re jig the model before posting it to the View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought DisplayFor would detect this and create a CheckBox for the boolean strings.

DisplayFor never creates any input fields, unless of course you write a custom template that will generate a checkbox (but I wouldn't do that). That's the whole point of display templates. It's for displaying only.

If you want to generate input fields use an editor template (`Html.EditorFor`).

Take a look at how the [default templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) look like.

Comment: Yes, I'm confusing myself and the issue because the first two strings I only want to display but of course eventually I'll want my user to edit the checkboxes. Thanks, I'll re-think the model!!